# Sitecore Custom Cache Size

Tags: caching

I created sitecore custom cache. the cache is showing up in the cache.aspx page (
sitecore/admin/cache.aspx) but showing the size as zero. but when i put log in code i am seeing the data saved in cache and getting retrieved from cache.

Comment: You have to tell the cache what size your object is. Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you add your object to the cache, you have to use an object that is derived from a class that inherits ICacheable. The property GetDataLength is what tells Sitecore cache what size the object is. Please make sure that GetDataLength() is being assigned a value.

You can see an example [here](https://laubplusco.net/create-custom-cache-sitecore/).

```
public class MyCacheClass : ICacheable
{
    public long GetDataLength()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public bool Cacheable { get; set; }
    public bool Immutable { get; }
    public event DataLengthChangedDelegate DataLengthChanged;
}
```